# Android: What is the proper way to add action buttons to the Toolbar widget from the Support Library?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Here's my toolbar style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/md_blue_500">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:title="@string/next_text"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_white_18dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">  
    </item>



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I am adding this Toolbar to my Activity Layout using:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">

</include>
```

From there, I've set it as my Action Bar in my onCreate method to basically say: hey Android, I don't want to use your Action Bar, I've got my own.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bnew_account);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // I'm not using your action bar anymore
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 
}
```

For some reason it crashes my app if I put the item element in my toolbar style:

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:title="@string/next_text"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_white_18dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">  
    </item>
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Put your `<item>` in a menu resource, and load that into the `Toolbar`. I haven't played with this just yet to see whether you load the menu resource via `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or `inflateMenu()` in the "make-the-`Toolbar`-be-my-action-bar" scenario.

Answer (score 1):

While slightly out of date, the [adding action items to the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) training shows how you to add action items via a [menu resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html). When you call `setSupportActionBar()` with your `Toolbar`, calls to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` will be routed automatically to your `Toolbar`, making it a drop in replacement for a standard Action Bar.